# Class CloudStorageTools not found

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to get working CloudStorageTools from Google Cloud into a Laravel project and I'm facing some errors at the time of using this class from the already installed SDK. **This is failing in dev server and also in Google deployed server.**

Im trying to get an URL for resizing purposes following the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/images)

```
use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;

$options = ['size' => 400, 'crop' => true];
$image_file = "gs://${my_bucket}/image.jpg";
$image_url = CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl($image_file, $options);
```

If I follow that documentation I get:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class
>   'google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools' not found

So I manually required the class which is in:

> /root/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/php/sdk/google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php

And it worked but throws me the next error also:

> PHP error:  Class 'google\appengine\util\StringUtil' not found in
>   /root/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/php/sdk/google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php
>   on line 464

I think that what I'm trying to do is kinda tricky and it is not the proper way to do this.

I installed the SDK as root, could this be a problem?

Comment: It looks like you are missing an autoloader.  Can you show us your bootstrap file? Or are you perhaps using Composer for this project?

Comment: Yes, of course, Laravel uses composer @Flosculus